# Returning different types to a View after a join (ASP.NET MVC2 C#)

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-2, view, parameters

Here's my problem: I have a sql query that, after a series of join, grabs some data from different tables.

This data belongs on different classes. How can I access this data from the view?

i.e.:

```
Classes:
-Customers (id,name)
-Books (id, author, title)
-BookCopies (id, idBook)
-Rentals(idCustomer, dateRental, dateRestituition)
```

I want a List of (BookCopies.id, Customer.id, Customers.name, Books.title, Rentals.dateRental, Rentals.dateRestituition).

How can i do it?

Comment: How are you retrieving the data from the join? Just create a View Model class with the properties needed by the view, then populate from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a single class that contains the information from the SQL view. If this is the case, then you can create a new class that contains the various fields:

```
public class RentalDetails
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateRental { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateRestitution { get; set; }
}
```

To make population of this class easier, you will probably want to provide aliases in your SQL View. For example:

```
SELECT BookCopies.id As BookId ,
       Customer.id As CustomerId
etc...
```